# Why ADT "data MyC c = EmptyC | ConsC c MyC" not type safe?

Tags: haskell, abstract-data-type

```
--This is type safe 
data IntList = Empty | Cons Int IntList
  deriving Show

--This is type safe
data MyB b = EmptyB | ConsB b b
  deriving Show

data MyC c = EmptyC | ConsC c MyC
  deriving Show
```

Why is abstract data type MyC not type safe ?
The gaurd clause `ConsC c MyC` should construct the
Cons list as it is invokding `MyC` in same way that IntList
is invoked from  `Cons Int IntList` for `IntList` ADT ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not *valid*, it has nothing to do with safety, it is simply incorrect.

```
data MyC c = EmptyC | ConsC c MyC
```

The problem here is that `MyC` takes an argument, but when it is used, it is not given an argument.  It should be as follows:

```
data MyC c = EmptyC | ConsC c (MyC c)
--                            ^^^^^^^ The parameter is necessary
```

Note that `MyC Int` is basically the same as `IntList`.